# Githubのみでローカルフォルダをアップロードしたい　（Git利用せず）

Tags: github

Githubのみでローカルフォルダをアップロードしたい　（GitやFTPソフトを利用せず）

ファイルはアップロードできるのですが、

フォルダを作って、そこにフォルダやファイルをアップロードしたい

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

空のフォルダのみを作成する方法は無いみたいなので、ダミーでも構わないので空のファイルを以下の手順で作成してみてください。
リポジトリのトップ画面にある`Create new file`で新規ファイルの作成画面に移るので、ファイル名の入力欄に`/`で区切れば自動でフォルダが作成されるようです。

参考:
[Creating new folders in GitHub repository via the browser](https://github.com/KirstieJane/STEMMRoleModels/wiki/Creating-new-folders-in-GitHub-repository-via-the-browser)

[image]

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました

Answer (score 2):

[英語版スタックオーバーフローにおける同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773598/creating-folders-inside-github-com-repo-without-using-git)が参考になります。

ファイルを作るインターフェースで`/`（スラッシュ）をファイル名に用いることで、そのファイルを新しいフォルダの中に作ることができます。リンク先は英語ですが、動画があるのでやり方が分かるかと思います。

注意点としては、この方法だとフォルダを作ると同時にその中にファイルができるということです。gitでは空のフォルダは扱われないためこれは避けられない制約です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。